# Get all field names from all tables in Sybase DB

Tags: sybase

I've been tasked to get all the fields in all tables in a Sybase DB. Anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/723115/how-do-i-look-at-column-metadata-in-sybase

Answer (score 2):

EXEC sp_columns your_table_name

Answer (score 1):

There's also a SAP/Sybase utility called "ddlgen" which can generate a db schema.  See:

http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc30191.1550/html/utility/CHDBBGGC.htm

Example to extract the schema for a db:

```
ddlgen -S<server> -U<login> -D<database> -O<output file>
```

(note, the above example creates a file which contains commands to drop and recreate your database)

Note, you can filter by object type using -T and filter by object name using -N.  If you use these options, the schema gets generated with "drop and recreate" commands.